# Unable to install IBM SDK for nodejs on Window 10

Tags: node.js, sdk

I am unable to install "ibm-6.9.1.0-node-v6.9.1-win-x64.exe" on my Windows 10. I am getting the following exception.

[image]

When I click on details , The following error message is visible-

```
Flexeraax2$aaa: Windows DLL failed to load
    at Flexeraax2.af(Unknown Source)
    at Flexeraax2.aa(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by calling for console:

```
C:....> ibm-6.10.1.0-node-v6.10.1-win-x64 LAX_VM "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe”
```